# How to control when Imports are replaced by wildcard in Android Studio in Kotlin files

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I noticed that for up to 4 imports from the same package, auto-import will simply append the import in the list:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

But adding a 5th import will make auto-import switch to a wildcard:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.*
```

Is there a way to keep auto-import on but tell it to not do that, or change the threshold? I don't mind having a long list of imports, it feels... familiar.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set this under the Kotlin "Code Style" section in Preferences:

[image: Imports]

Comment: `Use single name import` turns it off for good, it seems. Great stuff! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The [Android Kotlin Style Guide](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide) says:

> Wildcard imports (of any type) are **not allowed**.

You can set your Android Studio preferences to remove all wildcard imports from Kotlin files.

1. Open Android Studio Preferences: `Editor > Code Style > Kotlin`
2. Select `Use single name import` for *Top-level Symbols*
3. Select `Use single name import` for *Java Statics and Enum Members*
4. Remove all packages from *Packages to Use Import with* by clicking the minus `-` symbol until it says `Nothing to show`

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio 4.1.2 Settings: No Kotlin Wildcard Imports]